# What's the minimumFontScale equivalent for SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13

I'm making an app in SwiftUI and the text looks fine on the iPhone but is way too small on the iPad so I was wondering what the minimumFontScale equivalent was in SwiftUI so I could have the text properly scale for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276919-minimumscalefactor) `minimumScaleFactor()` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`minimumScaleFactor` is an equant to `minimumFontSize` property

`minimumFontSize` property of the UILabel is deprecated from iOS 6.0 onwards.

An Alternative to the `minimumFontSize` is `minimumScaleFactor`.

If you assign `minimumFontSize/defaultFontSize` to `minimumScaleFactor`, it works in the same way as `minimumFontSize.`